# Insert values in to an object from loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a script that will insert some values in to an object.

I basically want to end up with a series of objects that would look something like this -

```
myObj.data.person[0].name = 'name 1';
myObj.data.person[1].name = 'name 2';
myObj.data.person[2].name = 'name 3';
```

etc

Here is my object which contains an array of objects.

```
var addressBook = {
  data: [ 
    person = {
      name: '',
      address: ''
    }
  ]
}
```

And a for loop to insert repeating information.

```
for (i=0; i < 10; i++) 
  {
    myObj.data.person[i] = {name: 'Joe Bloggs', address: 'Main Street'};
    console.log(myObj.data.person.name);
  }
```

Whenever I run this code I get the following error -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'person' of undefined at <anonymous>:14:24
```

So, the question is where am I going wrong ? And furthermore would this be considered the right way to go about creating a list of Objects (e.g. Person 1, Person 2 etc)?

(I'm ultimately thinking of how I can create something like a Person constructor and use a loop to create multiple Person objects).

Thanks,

Comment: You need to declare your `myObj` property correctly,

Comment: you declare your object as `addressBook`, but later try to access it as `myObj`?

Comment: `data: [ person = ... ]` is nonsense. If `data` is an array, then you cannot do `data.person[...]` either. You probably just want `data: [ { name ... } ]`, and manipulate `data[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to change your object notation in following way

```
var addressBook = {
  data: [{
      name: '',
      address: ''
    },
    {
      name: 'Roshan',
      address: ''
    },
    {
      name: 'Roshan1',
      address: ''
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: That's *half* the answer…

Comment: Thanks Isetty and Deceze. This was the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
myObj.data[i].person = 'John';
myObj.data[i].address = 'NYC';
```

Answer (score 0):

See this Answer as addendum to [isetty ravitejakumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6701984/isetty-ravitejakumar)'s [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42225267/3793309)

You should consider writing a prototype / class for your usecase.
In this case you could keep better track of your data.

maybe something like this:

```
var AddressBook = {},
    Person = {};

(function() {
    AddressBook.prototype = {
        data: [],
        add: function(person) {
            this.data.push(person);
        }
    };
    Person = function(name, address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }
    Person.prototype = {
        name,
        address
    };
})();
```

Comment: Thanks jayjay - that's also really useful to know. Beyond the problems I asked about in the original question - this is what I was ultimately trying to setup. Cheers.